# Get specific README.md data from Github API

Tags: github, github-api, readme

Recently, I started experimenting with the GitHub API getting specific data from public repos. Long story short, I want to grab specific parts of the README.md file from a repo.

For example, the master branch from Facebook's react repository I want to grab the text under the **Documentation** header the GitHub API. Is this possible? Any methods of achieving this are welcome. Thank you!

API : [React README.md API Data](https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/contents/README.md?ref=master)

Public Github URL: [React public repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the API, but one easy way is with `sed`; try this from a Linux command line:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react/master/README.md | \
    sed -n '/## Documentation/,/##/p'
```

This will return everything between the Documentation header and the next one.

Comment: Perfection! Thank you, using that works just as well 

Answer (score 8):

There is a very awesome way to use any GitHub repository MARKDOWN.md file with the use of API.

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{owner}/{repo}/{branch}/README.md
```

the above API returns everything in your README.md file in raw MarkDown format.
[api-use-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGVJ0.jpg)

Comment: This is another great idea, thanks! Then I assume you can parse the HTML or Markdown  after getting the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching content from the repository could be done like this:

```
curl -L \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
-H 'X-Github-Api-Version: 2022-11-28' \
https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO>/contents/README.md
```

The respons will be an object and the actual data is held base64 encoded under a key named `content`. Here is an example using php:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO>/contents/README.md");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
  'Accept: application/vnd.github+json',
  'X-Github-Api-Version: 2022-11-28',
  'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'my-user-agent');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = \json_decode($response);
$readmeContent = base64_decode($response->content);
```

The above assumes that this is a private repository, so if that is the case you will need to generate a new private access token and set the correct header. Of course you will also have to change the `OWNER` and `REPO` in the above example.