# How can I programatically access Stream Editor?

Tags: python, node.js, regex, sed

I'm looking for a tool/package (preferably in JavaScript or Python) that can access SED or perform the same functionality as SED tools.

In my case, I wanted to output specific text data from a file that is accessed via API calls. One solution was to use stream editor. However, I can't seem to find some way to programatically access  Does anyone know of such a tool? Or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Having Python, why would you want sed? What does sed do that python doesn't?

Comment: Can you say more about your use case?  Which layer do you want to do the replacement - before the API call returns?  Once the response is parsed?  I agree that usually you wouldn't call `sed` from `python` or `js` because the capabilities are usually easier to program in those languages directly.

Comment: Let me add some more context. This is building onto this question I asked a few days ago. I wanted to grab a specific text from GitHub README.md file from their API. The top answer was using stream editor to accomplish this task. However, I want to know if there is some programmatic way to achieve the same means.

[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605718/get-specific-readme-md-data-from-github-api/53605890#53605890)

Answer (score 0):

sed(1) uses a general concept called [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), which you should read about. Both [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) have built-in support for regular expression matching and substitution.